# c++/cli unable to use operator on get property

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm a newcomer in c++/cli, so i'd like to clear some things.

In my project i'm using the following code:

```
//fileloader class

ref class FileLoader {
public:
    property ProgressListeners^ DownloadProgressListeners {
        ProgressListeners^ get() { return progress_listeners; }
    }
    static property FileLoader^ Instance {
        FileLoader^ get() { return theSingleInstance; }
    }

 //some methods etc...
}

//progresslistener class


public interface class ProgressListener {
    void DownloadProgressCallback(Object^ sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs^ e);
};

public ref class ProgressListeners {
    typedef List<ProgressListener^> ListenersList;

    ListenersList^ listeners = gcnew ListenersList;

public:
    void ProgressCallback(Object^ sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs^ e) {
        for each (ProgressListener^ listener in listeners) 
            listener->DownloadProgressCallback(sender, e);      
    }

    void operator += (ProgressListener^ listener) { listeners->Add(listener);}  
};
```

and have to act like this, casue, as far as i understand, get property is unable to be used as lvalue

```
// somewhere in code

    ProgressListeners^ tmp = FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners;

    tmp += gcnew WindowsFormProgressListener(downloading_bar, m_log);
    tmp += gcnew ConsoleProgressListener;
    tmp += gcnew GUIProgressListener;
```

but it would be much better if i'm able to act like this:

```
FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners += gcnew WindowsFormProgressListener(downloading_bar, m_log);
FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners += gcnew ConsoleProgressListener;
FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners += gcnew GUIProgressListener;
```

I have no idea how to make this code correct and hope that i'll find advise here

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to do it the way you want? (Please don't make us guess.)

Comment: @DavidYaw here you are
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2676 binary '+': 'ProgressListeners ^' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator Launcher w:\unnamed_project\unnamed\launcher\LauncherForm.h 112 
but the answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
*FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners += gcnew TestListener();
```

DownloadProgressListeners is a ProgressListeners class reference and not an lvalue. Deferencing it you get an lvalue. The syntax you found:

```
ProgressListeners^ tmp = FileLoader::Instance->DownloadProgressListeners;
tmp += gcnew TestListener();
```

I think is a "trick" of ms compiler.

Comment: thank you @alangab

dont know why i didn't put " * " by myself, cause its really crystal clear, just got blunted for a second (maybe i should sleep more).

and according to the standart

_tmp += gcnew TestListener();_

shouldn't work at all, theese tricks of ms compiles casue сonfusions sometimes